# Vue Select close dropdown programmatically

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert, sweetalert2, vue-select, vue-sweetalert2

I use [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) in my project

When I use value and input alternative v-model

```
<div v-for="user in users" key="user.id">
    <v-select
                  ref="Vueselect"
                  :value="user.roleName"
                  label="title"
                  :clearable="false"
                  :options="roleCategory"
                  @input="item => ChangeRole(item,user)"
                />
</div>
```

**roleCategory**

```
  data() {
        return {
            roleCategory:[{value: 1 , title:'user'},{value: 1 , title:'admin'}],
            users:[{id: 1 , title:'Test1',roleName='user'},{id: 2 , title:'Test2',roleName='admin'}],
        }
      },
```

**ChangeRole()**

```
  methods: {
    ChangeRole(item,user) {

      this.$swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'Do you want to change permision!',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Change it!',
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
          cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-danger',
        },
        buttonsStyling: false,
      }).then(result => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
        user.roleName = item.roleName 
    }
  })
 } 
}
```

i use [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

the dropdown after select not close

***how can close dropdown programmatically***

Comment: Could you share `ChangeRole` method and `roleCategory` array?

Comment: @cafertayyar i update the question with **ChangeRole   and  roleCategory**

Comment: The format of `users`  is not true. It contains `roleName='user'` and `roleName='admin'`. `:` must be used instead of `=`. So, these must be `roleName:'user'` and `roleName:'admin'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [solution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-close-v-select-programmatically-after-it-has-been-opened-programmatically/61251/2) to close v-select programmatically.
In your case this may help you:

```
const searchEl = this.$refs.Vueselect.searchEl;
if (searchEl) {
   searchEl.blur();
}
```